# Mongodb filter with distance is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to filter the lat and long with maximum distance 10km.
Here is my nodejs mongodb code implementation:

```
  dbo.collection('CT').createIndex( { "loc" : "2dsphere" } );

     var findquery = {
       "GeoJSON.loc": {
         $near: {
           $geometry: {
              type: "Point" ,
              coordinates: [ 103.819839, 1.352083], //Long Lat
              $maxDistance:10000 
           }
         }
       }
    };


  dbo.collection("CT").find(findquery).toArray(function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
```

Data has stored like this mongodb:

```
[   {
    "_id": "5bc04226df7ea7503c7d57f1",
    "results": [
      {
        "ID": "FD02328677"
      }
    ],
    "GeoJSON": [
      {
        "city": "Los Angeles",
        "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -118.24532,
            34.05349
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "city": "Tampa",
        "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -82.45927,
            27.94653
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "city": "Seattle",
        "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -122.32945,
            47.60358
          ]
        }
      }          
    ]   } ]
```

When I run the code, I can get the result (by right I shouldn't), it looks like filter function is not working on my code. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few typos:

The index

```
 dbo.collection('CT').createIndex( { "loc" : "2dsphere" } );
```

should be

```
 dbo.collection('CT').createIndex( { "GeoJSON.loc" : "2dsphere" } );
```

Otherwise you get an error running your query.

The query

```
 var findquery = {
   "GeoJSON.loc": {
     $near: {
       $geometry: {
          type: "Point" ,
          coordinates: [ 103.819839, 1.352083], //Long Lat
          $maxDistance:10000 
       }
     }
   }
};
```

should be

```
 var findquery = {
   "GeoJSON.loc": {
     $near: {
       $geometry: {
          type: "Point" ,
          coordinates: [ 103.819839, 1.352083], //Long Lat
       },
       $maxDistance:10000 
     }
   }
};
```

In your query the `$maxDistance` within `$geometry` is ignored. There are no `$maxDistance` in `$near` so all records are returned.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have another question, what if I only want to show the coordinates in GeoJSON.loc that is within the maxDistance (10km) ?

Comment: Dear User 3736228, please take a quick https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get familiar with how Stackoverflow works. If you have another question you should ask a new question, or better search for similar questions that were already answered. Returning of matching elements from an array has been answered many times already. In any case comments are not intended for follow-up questions.